# Maintain rectangular shape without loosing image quality

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to re-size image in different screen resolution, I am using Bootstrap for making website,how can  I fit profile photo fetched from Facebook in rectangular box without compress and stretch the image in all resolutions and maintaining image quality. specially for Apple devices ?

Comment: The resolution only depend of the source of the picture, if you get only one picture for multiple resolutions, you can't upgrade his resolution...

Comment: The underlying image defines the image quality you can expect at different resolutions, so a certain amount of compromise is to be expected. The Apple APIs will provide something like the Windows stretchblt with good results, though limited by the original image quality.